# How to Implement cwd and other method in BLOB?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have one Abstract class which I have extended for SFTP type. I want to extend that class with AZURE BLOB type functionalities also.

```
export abstract class IDataSource {
  constructor(public logger: Logger, public debug: boolean) { }

  abstract list(path: string): Promise<File[]>;
  abstract read(path: string, writeStream: NodeJS.WritableStream): Promise<void>;
  abstract write(path: string, readStream: NodeJS.ReadableStream): Promise<void>;
  abstract createReadStream(path: string): Promise<Readable>;
  abstract createWriteStream(path: string): Promise<Writable>;
  abstract close(): Promise<void>;
  abstract exists(path: string, isFile: boolean): Promise<boolean>;
  abstract delete(path: string): Promise<void>;
  abstract removeDir(path: string): Promise<void>;
  abstract makeDir(path: string, recursive: boolean): Promise<void>;
  abstract cwd(): Promise<string>; 
 }
```

How I can Implement blob Storage related functionality with abstract methods implementations also.

Comment: are you using Java/javascript

Comment: yes...Javascript

Comment: it is like a mini project please tell me one operation which you required so you can take it  as a reference

Comment: I want to Implement `createWriteStream` method for writing blob data.

Comment: able to [send](https://i.imgur.com/kvFuNVg.png) [written](https://i.imgur.com/3OEpSCy.png) [data](https://i.imgur.com/zXzYedT.png) to [blob storage](https://i.imgur.com/ce8cYfZ.png).

Comment: abstract createWriteStream(path: string): Promise<Writable>; this method is needed to implement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253487/discussion-between-sampath-and-ashish-khokhariya).

Comment: as discussed giving you sample code with createWriteStream

Answer (score 0):

> I  have referred this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest)  and [CreateWriteStream](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-javascript.md) for uploading the given Content text to blob .

```js
const  fs = require('fs');
const  path = require('path');
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const  connectionString = 'connection String';
const  containerName = 'sampath78';
const  blobName = 'file.txt';
const  filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'file.txt');
async  function  uploadToAzureBlobStorage() {
console.log('Writing data to local file...');
const  writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
writeStream.write('Hello world!');
writeStream.end();
console.log('Uploading file to Azure Blob storage...');
const  blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
const  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const  blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const  stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
await  blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream);
console.log(`File ${blobName} uploaded to Azure Blob storage.`);
}
uploadToAzureBlobStorage();
```

With **createReadStream Output** :

[image]

Azure :

[image]

Other method :

```js
  
async  function  uploadBlob(containerName, blobName, data) {
const  blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString("connectionstring");
const  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const  blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const  stream = Readable.from(data);
const  uploadOptions = {
bufferSize:  4 * 1024 * 1024,
maxBuffers:  20,
};
const  uploadResponse = await  blockBlobClient.uploadStream(
stream,
uploadOptions.bufferSize,
uploadOptions.maxBuffers,
{ blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType:  "text/plain" } }
);
console.log(

`Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`,
uploadResponse.requestId
);
}
// Example usage

const  containerName = "sampath78";

const  blobName = "Hello.txt";

const  data = "Hello, world! Hi ";

uploadBlob(containerName, blobName, data).catch((error) => {

console.error("Error uploading blob:", error);

});
```

Output :

[image]

Azure :

[image]

[image]

**Reading the content in bolb** :

```js
async  function  readBlob(containerName: string, blobName: string) {
const  blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString( "connectionstring" );
const  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const  blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const  blobData = await  blockBlobClient.downloadToBuffer();
console.log(`Content of blob ${blobName}: ${blobData.toString()}`);

}

const  containerName = "sampath78";
const  blobName = "Hello.txt";

  

readBlob(containerName, blobName).catch((error) => {

console.error("Error reading blob:", error);

});
```

Output :

[image]